# Docker nslookup works but not wget

Tags: docker, dns, debian

I have the following setup:

- a dns server with an A entry for myhost1.mycompany -> 10.10.10.1
- a server myhost2 (debian11) with docker daemon (20.10.5) installed and a runing container mycontainer1 on it
- on myhost2, the private dns server is configured in /etc/resolv.conf with search mycompany

On myhost2:

- nslookup myhost1 -> 10.10.10.1
- ping myhost1 -> works
- wget myhost1 -> wokrs
- wget google.com -> works

On mycontainer1:

- nslookup myhost1 -> 10.10.10.1
- ping myhost1 -> bad address
- wget myhost1 -> bad address
- wget google.com -> works
- cat /etc/resolv.conf -> same output as cat /etc/resolv.conf on myhost2

So this is not (I guess) a DNS issue as nslookup queries work fine from the container, but I can't figure out why other application (like ping or wget) can't get the resolved ip..

Thanks for sharing your ideas !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior may be caused by the option `ndots:0` in `/etc/resolv.conf` which prevents ping from adding your default local domain.

In this situation, `ping myhost1.mydomain.lan` should work, where `ping myhost1` should not (and the same with wget).

So I suggest you can try to change it to `ndots:5`.

For example :

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:5
```